# C++ and Win32: When do I have to release variables etc?

Tags: java, c++, winapi, jna

I am usually a Java programmer and my C++ days were over for at least 15 years. Now I use C++ to build me a bridge (dll) for some Win32 functions.

The question remains, when do I have to release strings etc optaining from Win32 calls?

For an example: User32.dll => `WINUSERAPI UINT WINAPI RealGetWindowClassA(__in HWND hwnd, __out_ecount_part(cchClassNameMax, return) LPSTR ptszClassName, __in UINT cchClassNameMax);`. It gives me a pointer to the class name and I just map it to char [] using JNA. Do I have to dispose it after I copied it?

Are there any hints which and what to release / dealloc / dispose (?) / delete / free?

[Update]

As already being point out by technomage this example was all about owning the buffer being handed over. But the general question is when do I have to dispose it and when not? Is there any syntax or hint I can follow?

To give you an additional example, getting an interface (ISomething) and getting one of its properties. Usually one hands over a double pointer (ppVariable) so it can write a pointer value as result of operation. On one occasion I saw an follow up call of `SysFreeString` following up. So I guess I have to free it after using it.

Any idea about this one? How to handle it?

Also I have never seen that a window handle gets disposed (at least not in my code). What is the rule for that?

Comment: Could you add some code? How are you calling it? `RealGetWindowClass` expects you (the caller) to pass it a pointer to some already allocated block of memory. You might have to free that block of memory after you have copied it depending on how it was allocated in the first place.

Comment: [RealGetWindowClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633538.aspx) doesn't give you a pointer. It copies the window type to the buffer **you** supply. Dispose it, whenever you are done with it. If a Windows API call allocates memory for you, the documentation will explicitly state this, and how you are supposed to clean up that memory (e.g. [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) with the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` flag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a buffer to the native function and telling the size of the buffer.  That allows the called function to copy data to your buffer without having to worry about allocating memory.

You already own the buffer, so normal Java rules apply.

BTW, if you need to use `byte[]` with `-A` functions and `char[]` with `-W` functions.  That "out" parameter is defined with `LPTSTR`, so you need to choose your string type accordingly.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Bad choosen example. What about for example using a get_XXX method of an interface any rules for that?

Comment: @MartinKersten: The `get_XXX` functions of an interface are likely COM implementations, and COM resource handling rules apply.

Comment: Is there a link where I can see those rules?

Comment: @MartinKersten: [The Component Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms694363) is a good introduction. The section on [Managing Memory Allocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688453) explains the basic rules.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks. Since Techno solved the example problem (my blunder) the answer goes to him. But your information saved the day :-).

Comment: BTW, if you have functions that are returning allocated memory, you typically want to declare the result as a `Pointer` or some flavor of `PointerType` so that you can pass the result back to the context-appropriate "free" function.  You won't be able to do so if you declare a function to return `String`, for instance; you would lose the original buffer address in that case.